# Multiple search queries on one page

Tags: wp-query, search, query-posts

I need to display results of three different search queries on one page. More precisely, there is a searchbox on my page where a user enters a search phrase. Once the search phrase is submitted, I need to take the generated WP search query and modify it to build three different custom queries.

The results of these three queries will be then displayed on a page in separate blocks.

So for example, a user searches for the 'Honda' phrase. Then he gets the results of three search queries:

1. 'Honda' in custom posts called 'Cars',
2. 'Honda' in custom posts called 'Motorbikes',
3. 'Honda' in custom posts called 'Tracks',

I know that the simplest way to modify a WP search query is to use the `pre_get_posts` action hook, but I'm not sure how I can use it to create three separate queries.

Your advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query, but you will need to create new queries for the other searches. Use [`get_query_var('s')`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to get the search terms and create new [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) objects to perform your search.

Without more information it is hard to provide much more detail to the answer.

Comment: Thanks you for this suggestion. I'd like, however, to aviod building three separate queries from scratch, and modify the main search query as I would with `query->set()` when using `pre_get_posts()` hook. I will soon update my question with more details.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said-- "You can use pre_get_posts to modify the main query, but you will need to create new queries for the other searches."